# Data visualization solution for a download site

Tags: data-visualization

I'm looking for a flexible data visualization / reporting tool for my download site. By flexible I mean it should provide different kinds of graphs and can be easily configured. And it supports comparison among multiple target objects, e.g. I need to generate a graph to show 3 downloading objects about the download statistics in a certain period of time. I have googled the web and also in SO itself, google visualization api seems to be a good choice. Similar questions were asked but only a few gave satisfying answers. I would like to hear what the experienced developers say about this subject and have a broader list of options. If you have such experience, please shed some light and let us know what you think about the tools / implementations you have used along with the pros and cons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google visualization is a good choice.  We've used Google Visualization and have liked it.  The big downside to Google Visualization is that you are at the mercy of Google to continue providing the free service and have to agree to their [Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/terms.html).  That's probably not a big deal for most as their Terms are quite lenient.  We've also used [JFreeChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255717/dynamically-generate-jfreechart-in-servlet).

For more flexibility [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) and [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/) are very nice.