# JFree chart by using servlet in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, jfreechart

How can i draw a line chart by using Servlets and rendered Image?
I wrote a servlet and create a chart.but i don't know how to display it on my jsp page.

my servlet code:

```
public class GraphGen extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        genGraph(req, resp);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        genGraph(req, resp);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void genGraph(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {

        try {
            OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

            // Create a simple Bar chart
            System.out.println("Setting dataset values");

            DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
            dataset.setValue(30, "Girls","SCIENCE CLASS");
            dataset.setValue(30,  "Boys","SCIENCE CLASS");
            dataset.setValue(10,  "Girls","ECONOMICS CLASS");
            dataset.setValue(50, "Boys","ECONOMICS CLASS");
            dataset.setValue(5, "Girls","LANGUAGE CLASS");
            dataset.setValue(55, "Boys","LANGUAGE CLASS");

            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D(
                "Comparison between Girls and Boys in Science," + "Economics and Language classes",
                "Students Comparisons", "No of Students",
                dataset,
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true,
                true,
                false);

            chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

            // Set the background colour of the chart
            chart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.blue);

            // Adjust the colour of the title
            CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();

            // Get the Plot object for a bar graph
            plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
            plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.red);

            CategoryItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.red);
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.green);
            renderer.setItemURLGenerator(
                new StandardCategoryURLGenerator(
                    "index1.html",
                    "series",
                    "section"));
            renderer.setToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator());

            resp.setContentType("image/png");

            ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(out, chart, 625, 500);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Problem occurred creating chart." + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you already ask Dr. Google, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255717/dynamically-generate-jfreechart-in-servlet?

Comment: Thanks, what's the problem you encounter, what exactly does not work?

Comment: How can i display this image on jsp page?

Comment: You have to include a `<img src="path_to_your_servlet"/>` link in your JSP. Remember, in your case the servlet **is** the image.

Comment: i used this tag.but it didn't work.

Comment: If you point your browser directly to the servlet, does it show the image?

Comment: can you send me an example that work correctly?

Comment: Do you see any exceptions when calling the servlet?

Comment: @home's suggestion is correct. You need to link to the servlet with an `<img/>` tag. I would encourage you to provide more helpful feedback than "it didn't work."

Answer (score 0):

```
chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

            // Set the background colour of the chart
            chart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.blue);

            // Adjust the colour of the title
            CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();

            // Get the Plot object for a bar graph
            plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
            plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.red);

            CategoryItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.red);
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.green);
            renderer.setItemURLGenerator(
                new StandardCategoryURLGenerator(
                    "index1.html",
                    "series",
                    "section"));
            renderer.setToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator());

            resp.setContentType("image/png");

            ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(out, chart, 625, 500);
```

......Instead of above code just use this code this is more eassy......

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D(
                "Comparison between Girls and Boys in Science," + "Economics and Language classes",
                "Students Comparisons", "No of Students",
                dataset,
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true,
                true,
                false);


            try {

                final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo(new StandardEntityCollection());
                final File file1 = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath(".") + "/images/piechart/lineChart.png");

                ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, 600, 400, info);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);

            }
```

...............use this cod in jsp page.......

```
<div>
    <img src="path/images/piechart/lineChart.png"
         width="600" height="400" border="0" usemap="#chart" />
 </div>
```